# Find the formula for the sum: $1+3x^2+5x^4+7x^6+...+(2n+1)x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

The formula is supposed to be valid for $x \neq \pm 1$.

Here is how I did it:

$$\bar{S}_n = \frac{d}{dx}\left( x+x^3+x^5+...+x^{2n+1} \right)$$

The term in the brackets is the geometric sequence. So call the sum up to term $x^{2n+1}$ as $S_n$, then:

$$S_n = \frac{x(1-x^{2n})}{1-x^2}$$

and so:

$$\bar{S}_n = \frac{d}{dx} \left( S_n \right)$$

which gives me:

$$\frac{2x^2 (1-x^{2n})}{(1-x^2)^2}+\frac{1}{1-x^2}\left( 1-x^{2n}(1+2n) \right)$$

apparently, that's wrong. Embarrassing I cannot solve such a simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a minor mistake.

$$S_n=x(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{2n})=\frac{x(1-x^{2n+2})}{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is given by $$\frac{x^2 \left(-2 n x^{2 n}-3 x^{2 n}+2 n x^{2
   n+2}+x^{2 n+2}-x^2+3\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}$$

Comment: So my mistake is in the differentiation step?

Comment: I think so,you can compare with the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

**Without calculus:**

$$S_3:=1+3x^2+5x^4+7x^6
\\=2(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)-1+x^2(1+3x^2+5x^4)
\\=2\frac{1-x^8}{1-x^2}-1+x^2(S_3-7x^6)$$

and more generally

$$S_n=2\frac{1-x^{2n+2}}{1-x^2}-1+x^2(S_n-(2n+1)x^{2n}).$$

So

$$(1-x^2)S_n=2\frac{1-x^{2n+2}}{1-x^2}-1-(2n+1)x^{2n+2}.$$